# Launching program on system startup not working

Tags: c#

EDIT: I'm new to c#, I'm completely lost on this.

I have a program that is supposed to start every time windows starts up. I have it set it up so when you click a check box, it writes / deletes a regedit, code:

```
private void SetStartUp()
    {
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        if (LaunchCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            rk.SetValue("SystemStartupProgram", (defaultDirectory + "\\SystemStartupProgram.exe"));
        }
        else
        {
            rk.DeleteValue("SystemStartupProgram", false);
        }
    }
```

Where "defaultDirectory" is a custom set path. It's set up to be the directory in which the program itself is in, for example "c:\MyProgram\bin\Debug". The .exe file for this program is located in there.

This code works as far as I can tell, since if I go to task manager's start up section, it shows my program, it's location, and it's state, which is enabled. However, the program doesn't run on system start up.

I have a hunch it might be something to do with a .txt file my application uses. The file is located in the same directory. If I remove the .txt file and run my program manually, it tries to launch it but nothing happens. Maybe the windows start up doesn't find the .txt file, and thus can't start it? Is there any way around that?

EDIT 2: The program is a Windows Forms application. When run, it opens up a form. However, it doesn't show up when windows starts.

EDIT 3: Problem fixed, see answer below for details

Comment: You never appreciate a good logging system until you need to solve cases like this.

Comment: I think you drew a premature conclusion. You assume that your program never ran. Have you considered the more likely possibility that it ran but did nothing?

Comment: Not a conclusion, per say. I'm tossing an idea of what it MIGHT be to help solve this.

Comment: Let's start with a description of the evidence that makes you say that the program isn't running. What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? Also, how are you referencing the path to the `.txt` file? Are you assuming a "current directory"? Is it a hard coded path? Or are you programmatically determining your .exe install location?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. My application is a Windows Forms -application. When run, it should open up a frame. In my program I simply call StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt"); which creates the text file. At program launch I read information from the textfile with a StreamReader. So I would assume the text file's path is the current directory? My .exe is simply inside the default folder, bin/debug. (Using Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: If you want your application to run at start-up time, then you should create a 'Windows Service" application. Check out this Microsoft tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Comment: I googled for a bit and found that you can't create a GUI for a service application. I want the program to be a fully functional GUI based app. Other option I crashed into is, if I created a seperate program that had the functionality of the GUI app, but was a service app instead, and the GUI app would function as a "control" for the other one. Is this a good method?

Comment: Yes, split the service and the GUI. That is the proper way if the service should run independent of a user and even when there is no user logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long bug hunt, I found what the reason was. It was indeed what I suspected, when the program starts it tries to look for the .txt file located in the same directory as my .exe. Turns out when you start a program upon system startup, the directory it looks from is something like "Microsoft\windows32", which is not where my file is located at.

I set my program's directory to it's own folder (my case: bin\debug) whenever the program starts, and only then try to read the file.

The bug being fixed, I'm still going to make a windows service application version of it, since that seems to be the correct way to do things from what I managed to google. Thanks to everyone who helped :)